# Most elegant way to clean a string into only comma separated numerals

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

After instructing clients to input only

> number comma number comma number

(no set length, but generally < 10), the results of their input have been, erm, unpredictable.

Given the following example input:

```
3,6 ,bannana,5,,*,
```

How could I most simply, and reliably end up with:

```
3,6,5
```

So far I am trying a combination:

```
$test= trim($test,","); //Remove any leading or trailing commas
$test= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $test);; //Remove any whitespace
$test= preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", ",", $test); //Replace any non-number with a comma
```

But before I keep throwing things at it...is there an elegant way, probably from a regex boffin!

Comment: I think instead of just cleaning the input, you should also put input validation using javascript

Comment: That's a very good idea, had slipped my mind!

Comment: You could also let the browser handle this by using input type number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: @rypskar but would that allow the commas?

Comment: @mayersdesign if you use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) in your input you can specify a regex to allow. Just keep in mind that IE will probably not support this (maybe not safari either as it's a bit strange with input validation attributes)

Comment: No, sorry. Didn't read the question good enough. If you later are going to create an array of this and get the numbers from the array you might get what you want by casting the element to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a purely abstract sense this is what I'd do:

```
$test = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(",",$test)),'is_numeric')
```

Example: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/753f4a833e8ff07cd9c7bd780708f7aafd20d01d

Comment: That's very interesting, especially as I want to end up with an array anyway

Comment: That worked perfectly in my case thanks very much. I did assume that users meant to enter dots as commas, so used a preg_replace for that, and then converted to array using your code. Will now also add javascript validation as per comment above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = '3,6 ,bannana,5,,*,';
$str = explode(',', $str);
$newArray = array_map(function($val){
    return is_numeric(trim($val)) ? trim($val) : '';
}, $str);
print_r(array_filter($newArray)); // <-- this will give you array
echo implode(',',array_filter($newArray)); // <--- this give you string
?>
```

Comment: I see the idea, thanks very much, but seems a lot of code for what I assumed would be a regex stripping exercise. Could you please explain why it can't be done the "simple" way?

Comment: Because the string has numbers, words, spaces. so we need to trim, check for numbers, and filter.

Comment: It's actually the same amount of code as for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using regex,

```
$string = '3,6 ,bannana,5,-6,*,';

preg_match_all('#(-?[0-9]+)#',$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 5
            [3] => -6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 5
            [3] => -6
        )

)
```

Use `$matches[0]` and you should be on your way.
If you don't need negative numbers just remove the first bit in the in the regex rule.

Comment: Thanks very much, I knew there'd be a regex way.... there always is! haha